# a dump method twig return null instead of my object

Tags: symfony, twig

Could someone help me? I have some problems with the return of `{dump (app.user) }}` which is null.
However, I have got a user in my database.

So why it returns null?

```html
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Mon compte - La Boutique Française{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Mon compte</h1>
    Bienvenue dans votre compte. C'est dans cet
    espace que vous allez pouvoir gérer toutes vos opérations personnelles.
    {{dump(app.user) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not logged in.
Check out the Symfony debug bar in the botton. If it says "anon", then you're not logged in and app.user is null.

Comment: the Symfony on the debug bar on the bottom of my window?

Comment: it is surprising because I launch symfony serve in Visual Studio Code

Comment: where I should see "anon"?

Comment: why I need to be logged? because I may have a lot of users in my DB

Comment: More information about this you can find in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html)

Comment: You can install the debugger bar ([documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html)). `app.user` returns the current logged user, not the entire list of users in your database. Check out what  @DarkBee suggested

Answer (score 0):

Your user must be logged in.
I recommend instead {% dump(app.user} %} so that it appears in the symfony debug bar (composer require --dev symfony/profiler-pack) to install it.